# MongoDB - Update deep nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-update

I'm using Mongoose and ExpressJS

I have a schema like this:

```
{
  name: 'test',
  array1: [
    {
      type: 'big',
      array2: [
        {
          name: 'xyz',
          value: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to do some bulk inserts to `array2` to each document that has `array1.type === 'big'`. The code below works well.

```
myCollection.updateMany(
  { array: {$ne: []}, ...someOtherFilters },
  { $push: { { [`array1.$[element].array2`]: newObject } },
  { arrayFilters: [{ 'element.type': 'big' }] }
)
```

Now I want to be able to update properties in `array2` objects. I want to update `array2.value` everywhere where `array1.type === 'big'` and `array2.name === 'xyz'`.  I try this:

```
myCollection.updateMany(
  { array: {$ne: []}, ...someOtherFilters },
  { $set: { { [`array1.$[element1].array2.$[element2].value`]: 100 } },
  { arrayFilters: [{ 'element1.type': 'big', 'element2.name': 'xyz' }] }
)
```

What I got:

> Error: Could not find path "array1.0.array2.0.name" in schema

Don't know how I can manage that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Will recommend the modify the filter part to determine whether the document contains `array1.type === 'big'` and `array1.array2.name === 'xyz'` via `$elemMatch`.
2. The `arrayFilters` part was incorrect. `element1` and `element2` are different identifiers, thus they should be separated into different objects.
3. The syntax for `$set` is incorrect.

Your query should be as below:

```
myCollection.updateMany({
  array1: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "type": "big",
      "array2": {
        $elemMatch: {
          "name": "xyz"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  //...someOtherFilters
  
},
{
  $set: {
    "array1.$[element1].array2.$[element2].value": 100
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element1.type": "big"
    },
    {
      "element2.name": "xyz"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aS_KnbTHEjA)

Comment: Thanks but still got same error. As long as I use only one `$[]` element filters so only `$[element1]` or only `$[element2]` it works. Don't have a clue why it works in your playground and not in my code.